# Permissions for a pod on GKE to create disk on GCE

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine, google-iam

I am spinning up a `kubernetes` job as a `helm` `pre-install` hook on GKE.
The job uses `google/cloud-sdk` image and I want it to create a compute engine persistent disk.

Here is its `spec`:

```
    spec:
      restartPolicy: OnFailure
      containers:
      - name: create-db-hook-container
        image: google/cloud-sdk:latest
        command: ["gcloud"]
        args: ["compute", "disks", "create", "--size={{ .Values.volumeMounts.gceDiskSize  }}", "--zone={{ .Values.volumeMounts.gceDiskZone }}", "{{ .Values.volumeMounts.gceDiskName }}"]
```

However this fails with the following error:

```
brazen-lobster-create-pd-hook-nc2v9 create-db-hook-container ERROR: 
(gcloud.compute.disks.create) Could not fetch resource: brazen-lobster-create-pd-hook-nc2v9 
create-db-hook-container  
- Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes. 
brazen-lobster-create-pd-hook-nc2v9 create-db-hook-container
```

Apparently I have to grant the `gcloud.compute.disks.create` permission.

My question is **to whom I have to grant this permission**?

This is a GCP IAM permission therefore I assume it cannot be granted specifically on a `k8s` resource (?) so it cannot be dealt within the context of `k8s` RBAC, right?

**edit**: I have created a `ComputeDiskCreate` custom role, that encompasses two permissions:

- `gcloud.compute.disks.create`
- `gcloud.compute.disks.list`

I have attached it to service account

`service-2340842080428@container-engine-robot.uam.gserviceaccount.com` that my `IAM` google cloud console has given the name

> Kubernetes Engine Service Agent

but the outcome is still the same.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren’t creating the disk through the Kubernetes persistent volume system?

Comment: I want to avoid PVs/PVCs (It will be an one-off process) so I opted for pure `k8s` volumes --> https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#gcepersistentdisk. Is there a way to create the actual persistent disk other than `gcloud compute disk create` ?

Comment: No, that’s what the pvc system is for though, to automatically create the volume for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GKE, all nodes in a cluster are actually Compute Engine VM instances. They're assigned a service account at creation time to authenticate them to other services. You can check the service account assigned to nodes by checking the corresponding node pool.

By default, GKE nodes are assigned the Compute Engine default service account, which looks like `PROJECT_NUMBER-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com`, unless you set a different one at cluster/node pool creation time.

Calls to other Google services (like the `compute.disks.create` endpoint in this case) will come from the node and be authenticated with the corresponding service account credentials.

You should therefore add the `gcloud.compute.disks.create` permission to your nodes' service account (likely `PROJECT_NUMBER-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com`) in your Developer Console's [IAM page](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam).

**EDIT**: Prior to any authentication, the mere ability for a node to access a given Google service is defined by its [access scope](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts#accesscopesiam). This is defined at node pool's creation time and can't be edited. You'll need to create a new node pool and ensure you grant it the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute` access scope to Compute Engine methods. You can then instruct your particular pod to [run on those specific nodes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/).

Comment: I tried you suggestion, I even assigned the entire `Compute Storage Admin` role to the Compute Engine default role. Now I am getting `- Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.` Any ideas?

Comment: pkaramol@, I've updated my answer to address the authentication scope issue.